# Deserialize Key-Value pair XML to Class object

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I have XML having Key Value Pair as mentioned below:

```
<Employee>
    <item>
        <key>Name</key>
        <value>XYZ</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>Phone</key>
        <value>1234567890</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>Date of Birth</key>
        <value>19-06-1984</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>Employee ID</key>
        <value>1</value>
    </item>
</Employee>
```

And I have Property class as mentioned below:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }

    public int? Id { get; set; }
}
```

I need to deserialize this XML to property class but I don't understand proper way to achieve this.

I can achieve it using `Reflection` but I heard that `Reflection` degrades performance so want to know that is there any better way to achieve this ?

Comment: Try to achieve this using LINQ to XML, try out something yourself first, if no luck - post your code here

Comment: Reflection may degrade performance, but chances are you won't notice it in most applications.

Comment: @Moo-Juice: You are right. But I have very large xml. This is just a sample I have provided.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: I have heard `XmlSerializer` but do you think XML posted in question can be deserialized to this object ?

Comment: @user2988458 I didn't notice you were storing it in a key-value kind of way.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: :) thats the only reason to post this question.

Comment: @user2988458 `If (key == "Name") {Name = value}` etc.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: Its not a proper way to do like this. What If i have xml which is having 100 nodes ?

Comment: @user2988458 Is "item" inside an array?

Comment: @user2988458 Then use a `switch` statement so that the compiler can buid a hash table of the possible values.

Comment: (It would have been better if I'd written "keys" rather than "values" there.)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: No. Item it selft array. Employee is the root element.

Answer (score 1):

```
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Employee));
        using (var reader = new StringReader("Your xml"))
        {
            var _emp = (Employee)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

            var _emp2 = new Employee2()
            {
                DOB = _emp.Items.Where(x => x.key == "Date of Birth").Select(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.value)).First(),
                Name = _emp.Items.Where(x => x.key == "Name").Select(x => x.value).First(),
                Phone = _emp.Items.Where(x => x.key == "Phone").Select(x => x.value).First(),
                Id = _emp.Items.Where(x => x.key == "Employee ID").Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.value)).First()

            };

        }
```

Class for desirialization

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Employee
{

    private EmployeeItem[] itemsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("item", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public EmployeeItem[] Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class EmployeeItem
{

    private string keyField;

    private string valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string key
    {
        get
        {
            return this.keyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.keyField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't like this solution, because the complexity more then it should be.
If I faced this task, I would use automapper. But I don't remember the right syntax for it.

Answer (score 0):

this should do it

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
XElement xElement = XElement.Load("Employees.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> xmlEmployees = xElement.Elements("Employee");
foreach (var xmlEmployee in xmlEmployees)
{
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    foreach (var item in xmlEmployee.Elements("item"))
    {
        string key = item.Element("key").Value;
        string value = item.Element("value").Value;
        switch (key)
        {
            case "Name":
                employee.Name = value;
                break;
            ...
        }
    }
    employees.Add(employee);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement `IXmlSerializable` like this:

```
public class Employee : IXmlSerializable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }

    public int? Id { get; set; }

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    if (string.Equals(reader.Name, "item", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        // move to 'key'
                        reader.Read();
                        if (reader.Name != "key") throw new SerializationException();
                        string key = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        if (reader.Name != "value") throw new SerializationException();
                        switch (key)
                        {
                            case "Name":
                                this.Name = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                break;
                            case "Phone":
                                this.Phone = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                break;
                            case "Date of Birth":
                                this.DOB = DateTime.Parse(reader.ReadElementContentAsString());
                                break;
                            case "Employee ID":
                                this.Id = reader.ReadElementContentAsInt();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // something was wrong
                        throw new SerializationException();
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                    reader.Read();
                    return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And use with standart `XmlSerializer`:

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Employee));
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(@"D:\Temp\employee.xml"))
{
    var item = ser.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can give this a try. This is simple and subtle.

   using System;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Xml.Serialization;
   using System.Xml;
   using System.Text;

   namespace ConsoleApplication1
   {
       class Program
       {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                 Employee emp = new Employee
                 {
                     Name = new Item { Key = "Name", Value = "XYZ" },
                     Phone = new Item { Key = "Phone", Value = "007987" },
                     DOB = new Item { Key = "Date of Birth", Value = "Some Date"},
                     Id = new Item { Key = "Employee ID", Value = "A ID" },
                 };

            var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Employee));

            using (var fs = new StreamWriter("your path", false))
            {
                ser.Serialize(fs, emp);
            }

            var emp2 = ser.Deserialize(new StreamReader("your path"));
        }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "item1")]
        public Item Name { get; set; }`enter code here`

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "item2")]
        public Item Phone { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "item3")]
        public Item DOB { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "item4")]
        public Item Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```